# splitting a string using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, tokenize

I've been tasked to tokenize words from a corpus using regular expressions but I'm having trouble tokenizing abbreviations such as "e.g." or "i.e.". In particular, the one that occurs in the corpus that I'm looking at appears as `'(N.B.--I'`

```
string = '(N.B.--I'
pattern = r'(\w\.){2,}'
split_p = r'((\w\.){2,})'

match = re.search(pattern, string)
print(match)

split = re.split(split_p, string)
print(split)
```

`['(', 'N.B.', '--', 'I']` is the desired output list split however when I run it...

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 5), match='N.B.'>
['(', 'N.B.', 'B.', '--I']
```

I believe I can split the dashes with |-+

However, I can't understand why this B. is repeating

Comment: By what rules should the `--` and `I` be split? Your splitting pattern only concerns the repeating word character followed by a `.` dot. Should we regard the `--I` splitting as out of scope for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The split includes all *capturing* groups. Use `(?:...)` to create a non-capturing group around the `\w.` sub-pattern instead:

```
split_p = r'((?:\w\.){2,})'
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> split_p = r'((?:\w\.){2,})'
>>> string = '(N.B.--I'
>>> re.split(split_p, string)
['(', 'N.B.', '--I']
```

Next, if you want to split on repeating dashes, just add an alternative pattern with `|`:

```
split_p = r'((?:\w\.){2,}|-+)'
```

Demo:

```
>>> split_p = r'((?:\w\.){2,}|-+)'
>>> re.split(split_p, string)
['(', 'N.B.', '', '--', 'I']
```

This gives an empty string in-between because there are 0 characters between the `N.B.` split point and the `--` point; you'd have to filter those out again.

Comment: the OP said: *['(', 'N.B.', '--', 'I'] is the desired output*

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: sure, but they *mainly* asked *I can't understand why this B. is repeating*.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: they didn't specify any token rules that detail how to split `--` from `I` there.

Comment: that's only one part of the problem. How about to produce the desired output?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: We can't answer that part without clarification; I've commented on the question.

Comment: My main question was in figuring out why the B was repeating. Adding :? to the beginning fixed this problem and to deal with the dashes (-) all i had to do was add |-+ to the re finally yielding ((?:\w\.){2,}|-+) which appropriately splits to ['(', 'N.B.', '', '--', 'I']   (The empty strings aren't a problem) Thanks Roman!!!

Comment: @VladimirPapov: so the other rule is to split on dashes, thanks. You could add that to your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, sorry btw I meant to say thanks to you the original answer. First time actually asking a question on this site and I misread the names. But thanks again!!